# Throwing in Combine map operator gives "Main actor-isolated property 'foo' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context"

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have the following operator in a Combine pipeline, which must be run on the main thread, before returning to the global dispatch queue. That's because `FooManager.shared.foo` is on the `MainActor`:

```
extension AnyPublisher where Output == (Foo, Bar), Failure == Error {
  func checkForFoo() -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
    self
      .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
      .tryMap { x, y in
        let isFoo = FooManager.shared.foo // Error here
        if isFoo {
          guard FooManager.shared.bar == true else {
            throw MyError.cancelled
          }
        }
        return (x, y)
      }
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

Throwing from inside the guard causes the error `Main actor-isolated property 'foo' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context`. However, if I just return nothing from the guard statement, it doesn't do this. I need to be able to throw, but I don't understand why it's mentioning the main actor stuff, when I've switched to receive on the main runloop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the compiler doesn't know that you've switched to the main thread, you do that at runtime, but the compiler doesn't know that when it compiles your code.

Second, the `MainActor` and the main thread are two different things.  The `MainActor` guarantees that, when it is running code, the thread it is running that code on will be the only thread running `MainActor` code.  That does not guarantee your code will run on the main thread.  But if it's running on another thread, the main thread will be suspended.

Finally the complaint you are seeing from the compiler is not that you're code is not on the main thread, but that you are using `async` code in a non `async` context.  Because `FooManager` is (apparently) actor isolated (which actor is immaterial), any calls to it must be `await`ed and you can only use `await` in an asynchronous context.  Here the closure you pass to `tryMap` is a synchronous context, it's not allowed to suspend, so the compiler complains.

Comment: "That does not guarantee your code will run on the main thread." - can you elaborate on this a bit? as i understand it, as the `MainActor`'s executor is the main dispatch queue and the main dispatch queue's blocks are guaranteed to run on the main thread.

Comment: Even when using dispatch queues, you should not check to see if the current queue is the main dispatch queue when running your code because you may be running on a dispatch queue that targets the main queue, but not on the main queue itself.  Similarly the actor pattern guarantees that protected code in the actor will be running in isolation relative to to other protected code, but that does not mean that the code is running on the main thread.  It could be running on another thread, while the "main thread" is suspended.  Folks have observed this in other questions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ScottThompson, could you please provide any evidence to support your comment? The reason I'm asking is that it's a pretty important and serious claim, and I would like to know more about it, but I can't take it for granted based on a single comment on StackOverflow, so if you could provide some references, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @FreeNickname I repeated the definition of what an actor is. In The Swift Programming guide actors "... allow only one task to access their mutable state at a time, which makes it safe for code in multiple tasks to interact with the same instance of an actor." (emphasis mine). The actor only guarantees that tasks have serialized access to the Actor's mutable state.  It makes no guarantees about what thread those tasks may be running on. The rest is in a comment on the function `dispatch_get_current_queue` in `queue.h`.

Comment: @FreeNickname Further at `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor/` it says "A singleton actor whose executor is equivalent to the main dispatch queue."  It is a executor that is "equivalent to" the main dispatch queue... not "equal to".

Comment: Thank you! Also the bit about queues targeting the main queue is mentioned in comments to `dispatch_assert_queue ` (for anyone wondering). I'm still not sure though, because main thread and main queue are also different things. But it gives food for throught and a topic for research.